# How can I tell my Winforms application to use the same icon for all forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, icons, ico

I have a nice icon and I want to use it on all of the forms in my application. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could have all your forms extend the same base class and have that set the icon.